# A neural network with peculiar architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning

I ended up working with a neural network $N(\cdot)$ characterized by the following structure:$$N(x)=V[\text{ReLU}(Ax+b)+Cx+d],$$
with input $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and parameters $V\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$, $A$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b$, $d \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Does anyone know what sort of "standard" architecture it represents?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the parameters? Otherwise, if $A$ and $b$ can vary freely, then $A-C$ and $b-d$ look like they don't do much, because neither $A$ nor $b$ appear anywhere else, which would allow $A-C$ and $b-d$ to be arbitrary with no loss of generalisation if you simply dropped the subtractions.

Comment: @NeilSlater You're right - just edited, accordingly.